# How to sort products by "featured" and price (ascending)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I am using Woocommerce Sort & Display Plugin in order to display all the products and categories on one unique page. It is working fine, however I cannot seem to sort products in each category as such: featured product first and then price (ascending).

In Woocommerce Sort & Display Plugin settings, I have set option "Product Sort" as "Featured". So my featured products appear in first positions. But what about the next products? How are they sorted? They do not seem to follow any logic as last modified, ID or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution to this issue.

If you want to be able to manually sort products with Drag & Drop when Product Sort & Display Plugin is active:

Search in file "woocommerce-product-sort-and-display/classes/class-wc-psad.php" for:

```
$orderby = 'date';
$order = 'DESC';
```

replace both lines with:

```
$orderby = 'menu_order';
$order = 'ASC';
```